# Imagem sempre após 2º parágrafo de um texto

Tags: php, string

Olá, gostaria de colocar imagem sempre após 2º parágrafo de um texto, pensei em substituir a 2º ocorrência `</p>` e troca-la pela imagem, mas não consegui fazer.

Comment: Mostre o que ja fez

Comment: Uma imagem diferente ou sempre a mesma imagem?

Comment: na verdade é uma div que vai receber a imagem e tals, mas o problema  mesmo é varrer o texto encontrar o segundo paragrafo que seria após o segundo </p> e subsituir por </p> <div>...</div>

Answer (score 0):

[**ideone**](https://ideone.com/GMy6nk)

Função para buscar a segunda posição da tag de fechamento    `</p>`

```
function pesquisarStrpos($palheiro, $agulha, $pesquisa) {
    $count = 0;
    $pos = -1;
    do {
        $pos = strpos($palheiro, $agulha, $pos + 1);
        $count++;
    } while ($pos !== false && $count < $pesquisa);
    return $pos;
}
```

Aplicação

```
$texto="<p>primeiro paragrafo</p><p>segundo paragrafo</p><p>terceiro paragrafo</p>";

$pos = (pesquisarStrpos($texto, '</p>', 2));

$textoInicio=substr($texto,0,$pos+4);

$textoFim=substr($texto,$pos+4,strlen($texto));

$result=$textoInicio."<div>...</div>".$textoFim;
```